# Gradle sync fails on fresh install of Android Studio, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu-16.04, android-studio-2.2

I've some experience with Android development in Eclipse but I'm a newbie in Android-studio:

- I download android-studio-ide-145.3276617-linux.zip and unzip
- I've java-8-oracle installed
- I execute /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
- once finished and SDK tools downloaded, I create my first MyApplication project with default options (all gradle files are the default ones, automatically generated)

I get:

```
Gradle 'MyApplication' project refresh failed
Error:Process 'command '/opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java'' finished with 
non-zero exit value 126
```

Tested in two ubuntu boxes. Any ideas?

Comment: Interestingly the older version android-studio 2.0 works well. Seems to be a 2.2 bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java is 64bit and I've a 32bit box. It's a pity that Google has discontinued support for linux 32bit. The workaround is to install SDK Platform-tools r23.0.1 (the last one with 32bit support) and do not upgrade to newer versions

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too in "Lubuntu 16.04.1 i686", but the answer here didn't fully solved it, but i think it's part of the problem. I tried changing the default proprietary java directory to the one in my system.

i found the hint for this in the official android studio release notes:

> "Android Studio now comes bundled with OpenJDK 8. Existing projects still use the JDK specified in File > Project Structure > SDK Location. You can switch to use the new bundled JDK by clicking File > Project Structure > SDK Location and checking the Use embedded JDK checkbox".

The default OpenJDK comes in 64 bits, so you have to do the opposed process described above.

- in the menu File > Project Structure > SDK Location, uncheck the "Use embedded JDK" checkbox
- change the directory for the java in your system, in my case, it is at "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_92".
  i had to change the RW permissions of the folder in order to this to take effect. As i said, I tried the "SDK Platform-tools downgrade" method first, i did the experiment of upgrading it again later and it synced, but later found another set of errors associated to it, so it have to be downgraded.